# Why do we think about things we regret we said before going to sleep at night?

Tags: psychoanalysis

We all say things we later regret during the day. Why does it often happen that at night, just before going to sleep, our brains bring those memories back and even make us lose sleep?

Comment: maybe what you are describing is [rumination](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/overcoming-self-sabotage/201002/rumination-problem-solving-gone-wrong)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is connected with psychoanalysis (in Freudian and post-Freudiean meaning) unless you want an answer from that perspective. I'm pretty sure, this happens as long as you are not busy - e.g. while you are in public transport without being stuck in a smartphone.

Comment: Where do you get the impression the question is asking in relation to Freudian or Neo-Freudian theory @rus9384?

Comment: @ChrisRogers, although it does not necessarily involve Freudian school, Freud has defined psychoanalysis and this question is not covered by it in any form. Probably this has more with behavioural psychology.

Comment: @chris I'm suspecting the [tag:psychoanalysis] tag.

Comment: Ah yes.  That teaches me to look at the tags